# InTouch - Cross referencing multiple tags

Tags: excel, wonderware

I have an old SCADA mimic project for which I must remove objects relating to 100 or so tags. **Is there a way of cross-referencing all 100 at once instead of cross-referencing one at a time?**

The names do not lend themselves to a single filter such as "REMOVE_ME_TAG_A", "REMOVE_ME_TAG_B" etc. I thought about renaming all these tags however aside from doing this manually I can't think of a way of renaming these tags programmatically. I hoped to use Excel but cannot establish a connection from Excel 2007 (I believe that only Office 2010 and Office 2013 are supported).

Comment: You can query using `*` as a wildcard in cross reference but it sounds like you're looking for an easier way to *remove* several tags at once, not just query their usage?

Comment: I have been tasked with upgrading a SCADA system. There are a huge number of tags which have addresses which have been repurposed (around 2500). A lot of them cannot be removed currently as they are in use. Each must be cross referenced to find which references must be removed. This takes 100 seconds per reference which is an absolute killer.

Comment: Yeah InTouch can be kinda crap for that. I'd say use the wildcard searches to reduce search time across multiple tags and also look at using the `Print` feature which lets you export entire windows/scripts to a text file which you can then use Find functions in Notepad++ or whatever app to locate tag usage.